# js access object property by value not by reference (sharing object call)

Tags: javascript, object

I call a property in object, when I update this one, the property is update too.

http://jsfiddle.net/zw8Ag/3/

```
object = 
{
    path : [1,2,3,4],
    test: function() 
    {
        var destination = this.path;
        destination[3] = 99;
    } 
}
```

this.path[3] return 99

What's the right way to get the data, not the reference ?

Comment: Your title suggests you already know why.

Comment: Yes, it's little bit more whath is the right way to get the data, not the reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because when you have an object in a variable, the variable doesn't contain object's data. Instead, it contains a reference to object's data in memory.

Then, `var destination = this.path;` just copies the reference, not the data. And if you modify one of the variables, both will be affected.

If you want to copy object's data, you can use

```
function extend(obj, props) {
    for(var i in props) if(props.hasOwnProperty(i))
        obj[i] = props[i];
}
var copy = extend({}, obj);
```

Or you can also try inheritance:

```
var copy = Object.create(obj);
```

Or in this case, since it's an array, better use `slice`:

```
var copy = arr.slice();
```

Answer (score 1):

Because it's assigning the reference not passing the value.

To clone the array: `var destination = this.path.slice(0);`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8Pvj5/